# Decrease page margins

Tags: columns, dimensions

I have found a very neat template for a cv. The problem is that I cannot regulate the dimension of the single column, resulting in way too much space wasted on the sides of the page. I would love to have "Second line" with less line brakes, that is, moving "date" more on the left, and leaving more spaces for text on the right.

How can I change this settings? 
Thank you.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} % nice cv style
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}


\renewcommand*{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Maroon}}
\renewcommand*{\cvlistheadingfont}{\large}
\renewcommand*{\cvlabelfont}{\qquad}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}
\begin{document}

    \begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{Title}}
        %\pdfbookmark[1]{Pers\"onliche Daten}{PersDat}

                    \begin{cvlist}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Section title}}\label{Conferences and Talks}
            \item[date] First line 
            \item[date] Second line Second line Second line Second line Second line Second line Second line Second line Second line Second line Second line Second line Second line Second line 
        \end{cvlist}  


            \end{cv}
            \end{document}
```

Comment: By "spacing" you mean margins?

Comment: Acv insn't different from any other document, so you can use package `geometry` to define the page margins.

Comment: scrartcl has its own KOMA based page margin adjustment system.  You can use it or geometry, just don't try to use both.

Answer (score 22):

Indeed, as suggested in the coments, done.

```
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
```

Comment: `top=1cm, bottom=1cm` can also be useful to set all margins

Comment: `\usepackage[bottom=0.5cm, right=1.5cm, left=1.5cm, top=1.5cm]{geometry}` sets all margins.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `geometry` package and write `\newgeometry{left=3cm,bottom=0.1cm}` where you want to change your margins. When you want to reset your margins, you write `\restoregeometry`.