# Getting 3 columns not equally because my content goes beyond my cell in last column?

Tags: tabularray

Is there a way to have my content inside my cells please ?

I've tried to "cut" the content of my second column and put it in additionnal row (i've tried `makecell`) so the content remains in the cell. But for my last column, the content goes beyond the cell. So why is the width of my last column not automatically increased especially when there is space to increase it and remains my content inside of my cell??!

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \begin{tblr}{hlines={blue}, vlines={blue},
                 colspec = {*{3}{X[l]}},
                 row{1}  = {c, font=\bfseries, fg=white, bg=blue},
                 row{even} = {bg=blue!10}
                 }
XXXXXXXX    &  \makecell{XXXXXXXXXX\\ XX}  & myververyveryvery@longemail.com\\
XXXXXXXX    &  \makecell{XXXXXXXXXX\\ XX}  &  myververyveryvery@longemail.com\\
XXXXXXXX    &  \makecell{XXXXXXXXXX\\ XX}  &  myververyveryvery@longemail.com\\
XXXXXXXX    &  \makecell{XXXXXXXXXX\\ XX} &   myververyveryvery@longemail.com\\
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

See the render please :[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is not clear to me what you want, but maybe setting `colspec = {*{2}l X[l]}` helps?

Comment: In showed example not. If the text is longer (than column width), it will be automatically broken into several lines. Please provide more realistic table content (you can simulate it by some dummy text). So far it is not clear, what you after.

Comment: Please, make a more sensible example of what you're trying to achieve. In the code you show there are only unbreakable items, so using `X` columns is useless. And, as it stands, the natural width of the table with `l` columns is a bit more than 18cm.

Comment: Is it better please ?

Comment: There's space? No there isn't, that's the whole page margin.

Comment: [columns - Decrease page margins - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291320/decrease-page-margins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be aware, that put an elephant into lady pears is not possible :-(. So, you should be very, very careful, what to put in table and how the cell contents can eventually be broken into more lines. This we can't do for you because haven't any information about your document and its desired design.

One of possible solution can base on:

- increasing `\textwidth` (with use of the `geometry` package)
- decrease font size, for example to `\footnotesize`
- at least in one column enable to break text into several lines

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \small % \footnotesize
    \begin{tblr}{hlines={blue}, vlines={blue},
                 colspec = {l X[0.8, l] X[1.2, l]},
                 colsep=3pt,
                 row{1}  = {c, font=\bfseries, fg=white, bg=blue},
                 row{even} = {bg=blue!10}
                 }
XXXXXXXX    &  XXXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXX &   myververyveryveryveryvery@longemail.com\\
XXXXXXXX    &  XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX &   myververyveryveryveryvery@longemail.com\\
XXXXXXXX    &  XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX &   myververyveryveryveryvery@longemail.com\\
XXXXXXXX    &  XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX &   myververyveryveryveryvery@longemail.com\\
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Above MWE produce:

[image]

**Note:**
For more possibilities and details about `tabularray` package see/read package documentation.